# Aristic rendering of breaking waves from a Japanese panel

Tags: graphics, generative-art

Any insight to model and render the breaking waves in the style of this Japanese panel?

[image: Waves at Matsushima]

Line drawings are acceptable, but not necessary to replicate all the details like foam, but capturing the overall features.

One possible starting point to generate variation might use Collatz-like difference equation the trajectories as the following plots with odd map $(3x-47)/2$, $(3x-43)/2$, and $(3x+17)/2$ for the interval of initial points `{1 ... 30}`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But that's just a suggestion and would still need to orient and tile the field.

Comment: +1 for an ID of the panel.

Comment: This is a detail from "Waves at Matsushima" 17th century. Tawaraya Sōtatsu , (Japanese, fl. ca. 1600-1643) Edo period. Ink, color, gold, and silver on paper. H: 152.0 W: 369.9 cm (http://www.vianegativa.us/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Waves-at-Matsushima.jpg)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Evidently Mma is much older than I knew :)

Comment: To my eye, the waves look like Sōtatsu drew them by dipping a comb in ink or paint then swirling it in arcs.  It looks like sometimes he held the apex of the resulting arc more stable then others.  One could begin to think about the directional variables to draw the waves.  Pretty extraordinary how the waves become clouds above the horizon.  I need to give this more thought.

Answer (score 4):

The draw remembered me [`ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html) pictures.

Here is a copy and past from Wolfram Reference:

```
data=Table[{-1-x^2+y,1+x-y^2},{x,-3,3,.2},{y,-3,3,.2}];
ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot[data,ColorFunction->ColorData["Aquamarine"],Frame->False]
```

[image]